# HugoでQiitaみたいなサイドバーを実装したい

Tags: javascript, html, hugo

QiitaのUIって見やすいですよね。Qiitaみたいなサイドバーというのは下記のような振る舞いを指します。

- サイドバーに見出しが表示される。
- サイドバーは一定以上スクロールしない。(本文をスクロールしてもサイドバーの見出しが維持される)
- 本文に対応するサイドバーの見出しがハイライトされる。

JavascriptやHTMLは触りしか知らない程度なのですが、実現のために必要であろう要素のキーワードを教えていただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hugoで実現したい場合は[こちら](https://gohugo.io/extras/toc/)を参照してみてください。デモは[こちら](http://gohugo.io/templates/content/)です。だいたい希望は満たしていると思うのですが、CSSでのスタイリングは必要ですね。

キーワードとして、位置固定はSticky。見出しはTOC（Table Of Contents）です。全てオリジナルで実装するのもそれほど難しくないと思いますが、上記のキーワードで検索するとたくさん出てくるので利用できるものが見つかると思います。